# Problems with Sliding a 'cookie policy' div into view

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I'm trying to create a simple 'slide-up' area (e.g. for cookie policy text) triggered by clicking a link. But my code has 2 problems:

1) The display text includes a hyperlink (targetting a new window) but when I return to the original window the slide-up is closed (it should be still open.

2) The 'Close' button does not work.

My code is:
CSS:

```
#cookieNote {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000; color: #FFF;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#cookieNote.closed {
  bottom: -5em;
  height: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="trigger">
  Open it
</button>
<div id="cookieNote" class="closed">Leave it<br/>
new line with link <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google </a><br/>
with close button 
<button class="trigger">
  Close it
</button>
</div>
```

Javescript:

```
$('.trigger, #cookieNote').click(function() {
  $('#cookieNote').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `.trigger` is a child of `#cookieNote`.

When you click the close button it's firing the function twice, so it opens and closes too quickly to notice anything. removing the `trigger` class off the second button would fix the issue if you want to still keep the whole `#cookieNote` as a trigger.

This is also why the hyperlink closes the cookie notice. They hyperlink is a inside `#cookieNote` which triggers the function.

**Edit:**

Using `.not()` is an easy way to fix the issue.
http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('.trigger, #cookieNote').not('#cookieNote .trigger').click(function() {
  $('#cookieNote').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.